# Propriety inside callback

Tags: javascript

Inside callback **requestPermission** i haven't access propriety **this**. How call method   InstanciarZona() in my class?

```
class PublisherPush{ ...

InstanciarZona(){
    let data              = {};
    data.zona             = this.Ad.GetZona()
    data.dominio          = this.Ad.GetDominio();
    this.Ad.StartSockect();
    socket.emit("conectado",data);        
    socket.on("Instanciar Zona",function(data){
         if(debug == true) console.log('7- Zona de Push instanciada...','Carregando campanha...');
         data.navigator      = navigator.platform;
         data.browser        = BrowserDetect.browser;
         data.os             = BrowserDetect.OS;
         socket.emit('Carregar Campanhas',data);
    });
 }   

 requestNotificationPermission(){
    const permission = window.Notification.requestPermission(function(permission){ 
    var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
    console.log('permission',permission,window);
    switch(permission){
        case 'granted':
            this.InstanciarZona();  
        break;
        default: 
            console.log('okay vocÃª nÃ£o concedeu permissÃ£o');
     }
     return permission;   
   });
 }

 ....
```

// value of permission can be 'granted', 'default', 'denied'

// granted: user has accepted the request

// default: user has dismissed the notification permission popup by clicking on x

// denied: user has denied the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main methods of doing this:

1. Add `const that = this;` before the callback then use `that` instead of `this` inside the callback.
2. Instead of using the `function` keyword for your callback, use an arrow function, [which does not have its own `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this).

Comment: there is also a third one with `bind` [Mozilla Developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)